# Dotted overlay over image to scale when bootstrap carousel size changes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap carousel and a dotted overlay over it.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/r4x99ecf/

HTML:

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/8hAR6s4.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/BPSXgEp.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Vk1Y6v0.jpg" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>$(".carousel").carousel();</script>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel, .carousel-inner {
    height: 350px;
}

.overlay {
    background: transparent url("http://i.imgur.com/8B7UFiv.png") repeat;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

My problem is, if you shrink the window size, the images' width will decrease. The images keep the aspect ratio so the height decreases as well. But the overlay has the same height.

How can I either get the overlay's height to shrink with the image, or overflow the image (less preferred).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `max-height` property to prevent this behavior

```
.carousel, .carousel-inner {
    max-height: 350px;
}
```

This way, you are assigning an `height` of say maximum of `350px`. Using `height: 350px;` fixes the `height` for that particular element which later causes the overlay image to overflow.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/r4x99ecf/5/)

Answer (score 3):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r4x99ecf/4/)

```
.carsoul{height:100%; width:100%}
.carousel, .carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}

.overlay {
    background: transparent url("http://i.imgur.com/8B7UFiv.png") repeat;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment or remove the following the part of css

```
.carousel, .carousel-inner {
    height: 350px;
}
```

Comment: So I guess I should crop the images to the height I want instead of setting the css height?

Comment: @Rickkwa If you want the overlay to adjust according to the image.. then this will do it.. why would you need to crop the images?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
.carousel {
       height: 100%;
       width : 100%;
}
```

& Remove your previous code

```
(.carousel, .carousel-inner {
    height: 350px;
})
```

Hope it will works fine for you!!